# How should we consider Catholic academic journals?

Tags: discussion

Mainly, how broad are Catholic academic journals? Do they ever deviate from the Vatican's opinion? If someone asks for a Catholic opinion, does that mean the typical Catholic layperson's opinion (may have expert knowledge and training on this subject), the Vatican's opinion (a very authoritative source), or heretical Catholic groups' opinions?

Answer (score 3):

I dinged curiousdannii's answer because I don't think it's a good idea to assume any old Catholic Academic Journal to be non-heretical.

Check the [Newman guide](http://www.cardinalnewmansociety.org/TheNewmanGuide.aspx) to see if the university has accepted the Mandtadum from the local bishop to adhere to Catholic Principles there are also oaths of fidelity that Presidents and Theologians ought to take if they're to be taken seriously as a representative of the Catholic Faith.  [this National Catholic Register article](http://www.ncregister.com/site/article/16007/) has more information on the oaths.

Answer (score -3):

I'd say that if an answer references a publication from a particular Christian perspective then it should be assumed to be validly speaking for that perspective. If that's not the case then competing references can be present in the comments and the answer edited accordingly.